# A Choose preference by dragging input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and would like to achieve the following effective

Preference for Option A --------------|----------------Preference for Option B

The use is then able to drag to indicate his level of preference.

I'm pretty sure some library exists that already achieves this, but I for the heck of me can't figure out what I would call it, to make a correct search.

Does this exist?

Comment: Is this a slider?
`<input type=range min=0 max=100>` is the fastest way to create slider, but works only for modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called a slider. Here's the [jQuery implementation](http://jqueryui.com/slider/). If you want to see another example, I use four different ones in my drawing tool on [my website](http://www.royhowie.com/projects/draw). And here's another example that uses jQuery sliders, [the filter.js steam example](http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/stream.html).

Here's the **[API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/)** for jQuery sliders.

Comment: Ah! Thank you Luxelin! :) Will click the accept button t minus 2 mins